# Calculate intersecting sums from flat DataFrame for a heatmap

Tags: pandas, seaborn

I'm trying to wrangle some data to show how many items a range of people have in common. The goal is to show this data in a heatmap format via Seaborn to understand these overlaps visually.

Here's some sample data:

```
demo_df = pd.DataFrame([
    ("Get Back", 1,0,2),
    ("Help", 5, 2, 0),
    ("Let It Be", 0,2,2)
],columns=["Song","John", "Paul", "Ringo"])
demo_df.set_index("Song")


        John    Paul    Ringo
Song            
Get Back    1   0   2
Help        5   2   0
Let It Be   0   2   2
```

I don't need a breakdown by song, just the total of shared items. The resulting data would show a sum of how many items they share like this:

| Name | John | Paul | Ringo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | - | 7 | 3 |
| Paul | 7 | - | 4 |
| Ringo | 3 | 4 | - |

So far I've tried a few options with `groupby` and `unstack` but haven't been able to work out how to cross match the names into both column and header rows.

Comment: You code seems to generate a different dataframe than the preview.

Comment: Thanks for that, looks like I pasted an earlier version from the notebook. Fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may do `dot` then fill diag

```
out = df.T.dot(df.ne(0)) + df.T.ne(0).dot(df)
np.fill_diagonal(out.values, 0)
out
Out[176]: 
       John  Paul  Ringo
John      0     7      3
Paul      7     0      4
Ringo     3     4      0
```

Comment: This is brilliant and works for my real data, thank you @BENY. I want familiar with either `.ne()` or `.dot()` so would never have gotten to this solution. I still don't fully understand it, TBH :) but will experiment with them solo afterwards to understand them better.